# How do I extract the number from a string vector and convert it to a integer vector?

Tags: r, vector, data-science, data-processing

I have a string vector in R as follows:

```
[1] Type 1 Type 2 Type 4 Type 3 Type 4 Type 6 Type 2 Type 5 
[9] Type 2 Type 3 Type 7
```

Also note:

```
str(data)
# Factor w/ 7 levels "Type 1","Type 2",..: 1 2 1 3 4 1 2 4 2 3 ...
```

I want to convert this to an integer vector to be able to perform cluster analysis (get cluster performance index). Because I am getting the following error: argument 'part' must be an integer vector

What would be the most effective solution?

Comment: I am not really sure if it is a good idea to convert a categorical variable into integer one for making a cluster analysis since ordering the numbers like 7>6>5... is not what you are seeking for I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str` output shows that you have a factor, not a vector of character strings.  It also shows that the level labels are `Type 1`, `Type 2` and so on.  A factor will represent the first level internally as 1, the second as 2 and so on.  So, supposing we have `data` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, to convert it to an integer vector we only have to use `as.integer`:

```
as.integer(data)
## [1] 1 2 1 3 4 1 2 4 2 3
```

If the label levels are not actually `Type 1`, `Type 2` so that, for example, the third level is represented by `Type 93`, say, rather than `Type 3` then we can implicitly convert to character and remove the non-digit characters and finally convert the rest to an integer vector.

```
as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", data))
## [1] 1 2 1 3 4 1 2 4 2 3
```

### Note

```
data <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: as.integer(data) did the trick. Thanks for this simple but great solution

Answer (score 1):

```
as.integer(gsub(".*(\\d+)","\\1",data))
1 2 4 3 4 6 2 5 2 3 7
```

We first remove the string part by only keeping the digits (`\\d+`) and then convert the vector to integer type.
**edit**
To capture numbers higher than `9`, we can use

```
as.integer(gsub(".*[:numeric:]+","\\1",data))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if number has two or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to boski's solution, which may be easier for ppl not familiar with regular expressions:

```
data <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub("Type ", "", data)))
```

This of course assumes that your strings always start with "Type" and a whitespace.

Note also that I convert to character before converting to numeric. Converting from factor directly to numeric can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

As there is only one instance of numeric values per string, an option is `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(v1)
#[1] 1 2 4 3 4 6 2 5 2 3 7
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 4", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 6", 
  "Type 2", "Type 5", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 7")
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for my case

Comment: @SakibShahriar  Not clear based on your comments

Comment: Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE

Comment: I got the above error but the other methods mentioned above did the trick. Thank you for your help @akrun

Comment: @SakibShahriar  YOu may have a factor column.  just convert to character `parse_number(as.character(v1))`